# how to create a zip file from a folder - php

Tags: php, file, zip, archive

I have a problem.

I searched the internet for a solution, but nothing works well. I'm trying to make a script that will take files from a folder and threw them into a zip archive.
But it doesn't work ..

I tried through different paths, but it's only me mixed up and nothing came of it.

Here is the current code that is according to me the easiest and should workbut doesn't do that ..

Can you help me?

```
function archivebackup(){
    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    if ($zip->open('Mail.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE) === TRUE){

        foreach (new DirectoryIterator('Mails/') as $fileInfo) {
            $fileName = $fileInfo->getFilename();
            // echo $fileName ."<br>";
            $zip->addFile($fileName);
        }   

        $zip->close();
    } 
}
```

Comment: what error messages are you getting? In what way is it not working?

Comment: First and obvious question, do you have zip support enabled in PHP?

Comment: I have no errors. The script doesn't add anything to the archive.
And I know that the program retrieves the names of the files.

Comment: Given that you are passing `Mails/` to your `DirectoryIterator` constructor, you probably need to prefix you file names with that path as well. `$zip->addFile('Mails/'.$fileName);`

Comment: I don't enable anything in php.ini. But I don't know that I have to.
This Code works if I give example "addFile("1.txt)".
However, when I want to do everything in the loop, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're not including files in your current working directory and `getFilename()` only returns a filename without a path.

Do the following:

```
function archivebackup(){
    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    if ($zip->open('Mail.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE) === TRUE){

        foreach (new DirectoryIterator('Mails/') as $fileInfo) {
            if (in_array($fileInfo->getFilename(), [ ".", ".." ]) { continue; }
            $fileName = $fileInfo->getPathname();
            $zip->addFile($fileName);
        }   

        $zip->close();
    } 
}
```

Comment: You're great! Thanks :)